# Theme activation hook in php class

Tags: php, hooks

I want to run a function when my theme is activated. I have to add the theme activation hook within a php class:

```
final class My_Class_Name {

    public static function getInstance() {
        if (self::$instance == null) {
            self::$instance = new self;               
            self::$instance->actions();
        } else {
            throw new BadFunctionCallException(sprintf('Plugin %s already instantiated', __CLASS__));
        }
        return self::$instance;
    }


   // some code

   add_action('after_switch_theme', array( $this, 'activate' ));

   function activate() {
      // some code
   }

   // more code

}

My_Class_Name::getInstance();
```

When I activate my theme I get the following php error:

> PHP Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid
>   callback, class 'My_Class_Name' does not have a method
>   'activate' in
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/wp-themes/test/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php
>   on line 288

If I use `add_action('after_switch_theme', 'activate' );`

I get

> PHP Fatal error: Cannot access self:: when no class scope is active

How can I make the hook work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are adding the hook just inside the body of the class. Try adding it into an `init()` method and calling it after it is instantiated or at the very least in the constructor.

I think the issues is that the hook is being registered before the class has been fully read by PHP?

Try this:

```
final class My_Class_Name {

    function init() {
        add_action('after_switch_theme', array( $this, 'activate' ));
    }

    function activate() {
    }
}

$class = new My_Class_Name();
$class->init();
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: That is much different than the code above? Seems like there is more to this than originally expected

Comment: yes there is more.. I updated my code

Comment: This is probably due to trying to call a method that is not static on a static instance. Based on the new error, I think there is still some missing code as it looks like they have a private constructor in the HXTR_Email_Subscription class.

Answer (score 0):

Just do not use "OOP" if you do not intent to treat things as object or extendab;e classes, use proper namespacing instead and save yourself the pointless headache.

Singleton pattern is not OOP and encapsulating global functions in a class brings no structural or any other kind of value, just forcing you to use much more characters to do anything.

The only use I found so far to have a singleton pattern in PHP is to be able to autoload the code, but in that case you do not need to create the object at the place you do.